# Apache forbidden access for subdomain

Tags: debian, webserver, apache2

I want to create a new vhost for an admin subdomain but I have a 403 Forbidden error.

I have this vhost which works well :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName dev.website.com
    # ServerAlias *.website.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@website
    DocumentRoot "/home/dev/sites/website.com/dev/public"

    <Directory /home/dev/sites/website.com/dev/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        # AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/dev/sites/website.com/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

But when I add a new host below the first one I get this 403 error. Though I just change "dev.website.com" to "admin.website.com" :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName admin.website.com
    # ServerAlias *.website.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@website
    DocumentRoot "/home/dev/sites/website.com/dev/public"

    <Directory /home/dev/sites/website.com/dev/public>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        # AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /home/dev/sites/website.com/logs/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

I have restarted apache but still not working. And obviously nothing in logs file (/var/log/apache2/error.log or /home/dev/sites/website.com/logs/error.log).

I work on Debian 8 and my Apache version is 2.4.10.

Thanks for your help !